# Determine if a subspace of $M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what it's asking. Seeing the transpose part is throwing me off.

Determine which of the following are subspace of $M_{22}$

> The set of $2\times 2$ matrices such that $A = A^T$

Comment: The set of matrices with $A = A^T$ is simply the set of symmetric matrices. So you are ask to decide whether a linear combination of symmetric matrices is again symmetric.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $M_{2\times 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$A=A^T$ are the symmetric matrices. Adding two symmetric matrices gives you another symmetric matrix, multiplying the symmetric matrix by a scalar gives you the symmetric matrix. Zero matrix is also the symmetric matrix. So the same sized symmetric matrices form a vector subspace.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that a matrix satisfying $A=A^T$ is simply a *symmetric matrix*. Consider the set of the matrices with this property and follow the usual steps to check whether a set is a (linear) subspace:

- is the set non-empty / does it contain the zero vector (zero matrix)?
- does the sum of two matrices satisfying $A=A^T$ have this property as well?
- if a matrix $A$ satisfies $A=A^T$, does the scalar multiple $kA$ satisfy it as well?

If all the answers are *yes*, you have a subspace of $M_{22}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that $aA+bB$ belongs to the same set where $a,b\in \mathbb R$.